# How to restrict Mapkit to certain zoom levels?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkoverlay, wms

Currently we are consuming a wms service instead of apple map. we override `LoadTileAtPath` to return the tiles from server.

Our problem is that as the applications is taking to much time load the map tiles at the remote areas with very weak network connection, So we planned to restrict the zoom levels to the below levels

**Levels**

```
1:1,250

1:25,000

1:250,000
```

with the help of document about [zoom levels](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels) I restrict z values to 19 or 15 or 11

Here the method

```
nuint ClampedZ(nuint z)
        {
            //19,15,11

            List<nuint> supportedLayers = new List<nuint>(){ 11, 15, 19 };
            nuint toRet = z;
            nuint min = supportedLayers[0]; //supportedLayers[];
            nuint Prevmin = min;
            nuint max = supportedLayers[supportedLayers.Count - 1]; //supportedLayers[supportedLayers.Length - 1];
            if (z > min && z < max)
            {
                foreach (nuint ZoomSupported in supportedLayers)
                {

                    if (z < ZoomSupported)
                    {
                        toRet = Prevmin;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Prevmin = ZoomSupported;
                    }
                }
            }
            return toRet;
        }
```

I just want to know if it is the correct way of restricting the zoom levels

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `MKMapViewDelegate`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    let maxLatitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 1.0 //put in appropriate value for your zoom levels
    let maxLongitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 1.0 //put in appropriate value for your zoom levels
    let center = mapView.centerCoordinate
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: maxLatitudeDelta, longitudeDelta: maxLongitudeDelta))
    let adjustedRegion = mapView.regionThatFits(region)
    mapView.setRegion(adjustedRegion, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: how to find the related z values for ratio 1:1,250 to be honest i picked 21 for 1:1,250 by just assuming after referring the document in my question

Comment: How can I calculate the `maxLatitudeDelta` and `maxLongitudeDelta` appropriate for the zoomLevel 16?